# Crossbar filter change current input to Composite

Tags: c#, directshow, capture

I am new to DirectShow. I am writing an application in C# for capturing from Analog capture card.
I have an analog capture card & I want to know how to change Analog Crossbar filter property, from "0: Analog Tuner In" to  "1: Video Composite In". Here is my Filter Graph

[image: FilterGraph]

I can not connect Tuner's "Analog Video pin" to "Video Composite In" of Crossbar filter. I tried running "Route" method of IAMCrossbar filter, which failed. I don't know whether my path is correct. Please guide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IAMCrossbar::Route` is how you do it. Make sure to read [Working with Crossbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details - it is C++ API, however I suppose you are using DirectShow.NET and it has similar methods.

Solution code snippet pulled from comment below:

```
IAMCrossbar Xbar = (IAMCrossbar)pNM8001AnalogXbar; 
//hr = Xbar.CanRoute(1, 0); 
hr = Xbar.Route(1, 0); 
checkHR(hr, "Some NM8001AnalogXbar Problem"); //CONNECT NM8001 Analog TUNER and NM8001 Analog XBAR 
hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(
  GetPin(pNM8001AnalogTuner, "Analog Video"), 
  GetPin(pNM8001AnalogXbar, "0: Video Tuner In"), 
  null); 
checkHR(hr, "Can't Connect NM8001AnalogTuner and NM8001AnalogXbar");
```

Comment: Yes Roman I have gone through the same and also tried samples viz- AmCap (SDK samples) and CapVideoTest(CodeProject), But, AmCap doesn't compile plus CapVideoTest does not capture.. So, a bit clueless how the application developers of Analog capture card figures it out

Comment: Hi Roman... I forgot to thank you for your reply...Moreover, This is my code. Please tell me if am doing anything wrong..

Comment: IAMCrossbar Xbar = (IAMCrossbar)pNM8001AnalogXbar;
            //hr = Xbar.CanRoute(1, 0);
            hr = Xbar.Route(1, 0);
            checkHR(hr, "Some NM8001AnalogXbar Problem");
            //CONNECT NM8001 Analog TUNER and NM8001 Analog XBAR
            hr = pGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pNM8001AnalogTuner, "Analog Video"), GetPin(pNM8001AnalogXbar, "0: Video Tuner In"), null);
            checkHR(hr, "Can't Connect NM8001AnalogTuner and NM8001AnalogXbar");