# Capture Camera Feed from EasyCap 4ch USB DVR Device using DirectShow and DirectX.Capture C#

Tags: c#, camera, directshow, directshow.net

I'm trying to capture the camera feed from an **EasyCap 4 Channel USB DVR Device** that i got recently
and i have bought a super Mimi Monochrome/Color Camera and connected it to the DVR Device and managed to correctly setup the device with the driver **"SMI Grabber"** and installed the software that comes with the Device **"SuperViewer"**
and i have wrote a simple windows form application that contains a `PictureBox` to priview the camera feed
(There is an edit in the bottom)
**The Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectX.Capture;


namespace DirectShowWithCrossbar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CrossbarSource crossbar;
        private Filters filters;
        private Capture capture;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            filters = new Filters();
            capture = new Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices[0], filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);
            foreach (Filter device in filters.VideoInputDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(device);
            }
            if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            foreach (Filter device in filters.AudioInputDevices)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(device);
            }
            if (comboBox2.Items.Count > 0)
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
            foreach (Source source in capture.VideoSources)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(source);
            }
            if (comboBox3.Items.Count > 0)
                comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ShowPropertPagesInMenuStrip();
            crossbar = (CrossbarSource)capture.VideoSource;
            crossbar.Enabled = true;
            capture.PreviewWindow = pictureBox1;
        }

        private void ShowPropertPagesInMenuStrip()
        {
            foreach (PropertyPage pro in capture.PropertyPages)
            {
                menusToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(pro.Name));
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            capture.Cue();
            capture.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            capture.Stop();
            capture.Dispose();
        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            capture.VideoSource = (Source)comboBox3.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

and i got a black screen in the picture box ??
[image: Black Screen No Feed]
[image: Super Viewer Software running]
and by mistake after closing my application i ran the **SuperViewer** application that comes with the **DVR device** and then open my application then my picture box began to show me the feed from the camera, **strange!!!** and the feed from the original software freezes !!
[image: Both my software and SuperViewer running mine is working the other is freezing]
DirectX.Capture Example and Sources tried with the same result http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library
and i have also used **OpenCV** and **Touchless** and i got the same result :(
**Edit:**
I have been searching and found that i need to get the filter (IAMCrossbar) i think that is the problem [DirectShow USB webcam changing video source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689763/directshow-usb-webcam-changing-video-source) and after appling the changes in this link in the **DirectX.Capture** Wrapper i still get the same results :(
 Thanks for any help in advance  **Yaser**

Comment: you can try using OpenCV, there is a C# wrapper for this library called Emgu, it will do the trick with a couple of lines of code... http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @user2247823 thank you but i have tried it and i got the same result :(

Comment: My guess is that the problem is with driver, esp. that it assumes that the application will set up cross bar first. It is hard to guess and has no generic solution.

Comment: not sure whether it's your code problem, because you didn't post your capture implementation. you can try to reference this article --[Webcam Capture](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Webcam-Capture-50295c7f)

Comment: @RomanR. thank you i think this is the problem to :( 
but can you point me onto how to do this

Answer (score 1):

If your capture device has option, to select one from multiple input interfaces, then yes, you are right about, that you needed to use IAMCrossbar.

If you want to stick to Directshow( as others have suggested OpenCV), then I would suggest,

1. Try building all capturing related code in a C++/CLI dll,
2. Build all your UI in C#.

You can take this [MP3 Player Sample Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/373613/Simple-Cplusplus-DirectShow-MP3-Player-Class) as starting point for your dll.

For capturing, [AmCap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a detailed example.

What I mean is that you need to get the capturing code out of AmCap into above MP3 Player Sample dll, and expose it to your C# application.