# Choose another source from usb device using directShow

Tags: c#, video, directshow, aforge, directshow.net

I'm trying to get image from a usb device using Aforge (directShow). The device (USB3HDCAP) has 3 diferent inputs (HDMI, DVI and S-Video). Using the code above, i can access and get the default input image (only from HDMI). However, when I change the physical input on the device (from HDMI to DIV, example) the image is black. What can i do to get video from other input (DVI or S-Video).

```
    LocalWebCamsCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice); 
    LocalWebCam = new VideoCaptureDevice(LocalWebCamsCollection[0].MonikerString);
    LocalWebCam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Cam_NewFrame);
    LocalWebCam.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is what just captures video. To switch inputs on video capture hardware you need to use crossbar to re-configure the device.

In plain DirectShow it is like his:

- [Crossbar filter change current input to Composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930867/crossbar-filter-change-current-input-to-composite)
- [DirectShow USB webcam changing video source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689763/directshow-usb-webcam-changing-video-source)

With AForge.NET you should be looking up for a similar method, e.g. see:

- [Start Capturing From S-Video](http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3035)

> ... VideoCaptureDivece.AvailableCrossbarVideoInputs gives array of available video inputs. VideoCaptureDivece.CrossbarVideoInput accepts what? - yes video input. So combine those two together:
>
> ```
> VideoKaynagi.CrossbarVideoInput  = CrossbarVideoInput.AvailableCrossbarVideoInputs[0];
> ```
>
> Of course you need to change 0 with an index of the S-Video input.

Comment: I will try the first one (DirectShow) because the second one, i already tried and i won't get any result from - AvailableCrossbarVideoInputs - array was empty.